# Creating MleaderStyle Autocad using C#

Tags: c#, plugins, autocad

I have created MleaderStyle in  C#.There was no error,but while i run it i get following error.Here is part of my code use for this purpose and error that is displayed by autocad.

MLeaderStyle dst =
                  (MLeaderStyle)acTrans.GetObject(
                  acCurDb.DimStyleTableId,
                  OpenMode.ForWrite);

```
        MText mt = new MText();
        mt.Contents = text;

        dst.Name = " My LeaderStyle";
        dst.ArrowSymbolId = ObjectId.Null;
        dst.ArrowSize = 0.18 * scale;
        dst.ContentType = 0;
        dst.DefaultMText = mt;
        dst.LandingGap = gap;
        dst.EnableBlockRotation = true;
        dst.MaxLeaderSegmentsPoints = 2;


        //dst1.Add(dst);
        acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dst, true);

        MLeader lead = new MLeader();
      int i=  lead.AddLeader();
        lead.AddLeaderLine(i);
        lead.AddFirstVertex(i, start);
        lead.AddLastVertex(i, end);
        lead.MLeaderStyle = dst.ObjectId;
```

**Error;**

Unable to cast object of type
'Autodesk.Autocad.DataBaseServices.DimStyleTable'to 'Autodesk.AutoCad.DataBaseServices.MleaderStyle'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MLeaderStyle dst = (MLeaderStyle)acTrans.GetObject(
>   acCurDb.DimStyleTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

You cannot cast the DimStyleTable into a MLeaderStyle, you have to use one of the MLeaderStyle constructors to create a new one.

```
using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    // the newly created MText have to be disposed after using
    using (MText mt = new MText())
    {
        mt.Contents = text;

         // check if the MLeaderStyle dictionary does not already contains a style named "MyLeaderStyle"
        DBDictionary mlStyles = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(db.MLeaderStyleDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
        if (!mlStyles.Contains("MyLeaderStyle"))
        {
            // create a new instance of MLeaderStyle (you can use the overloaded ctor to copy an existing style)
            MLeaderStyle dst = new MLeaderStyle();
            dst.ArrowSymbolId = ObjectId.Null;
            dst.ArrowSize = 0.18 * scale;
            dst.ContentType = 0;
            dst.DefaultMText = mt;
            dst.LandingGap = gap;
            dst.EnableBlockRotation = true;
            dst.MaxLeaderSegmentsPoints = 2;

            // add the new MLeaderStyle to the database
            dst.PostMLeaderStyleToDb(db, "MyLeaderStyle");
            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dst, true);
        }
    }
    tr.Commit();
}
```